# Время окончания скрипта загрузки Гугл Переводчика на сайте

Tags: javascript, google-translate

Как узнать когда завершилась загрузка скрипта Гугл Переводчика на сайте?
Где это можно посмотреть?

Answer (score 1):

Время загрузки скриптов/стилей/изображений и т.д. можно посмотреть в отладчике(DevTools).

В Google Chrome:

- f12
- Network
- Вкладка JS
- Находите строку с нужным скриптом
- Наводите на столбец Waterfall, там и будет вся подробная информация

Если поля пустые, то перезагрузите страницу не закрывая отладчик.

Comment: А как сделать так чтобы мой скрипт загружался только после того как будет полностью загружен этот внешний скрипт гугл переводчика?

Comment: https://www.cryptobaza.org/
Мне нужно убрать текст и картинку под самими переводчиком. Не знаю как это сделать.

Comment: @АлександрСалычев Как Вы реализуете запуск гугл-скрипта на сайте? Если прописываете `<script>...<script>` отдельной строкой в конце `<body>`, то просто нужно чтобы Ваш скрипт был прописан после гугл-скрипта.

Comment: Простите за мою не грамотность.
Я делаю так: в шапке сайта вставляю

  <script type="text/javascript">
  function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'ru', includedLanguages: 'de,en,es,fr,pt,ru,zh-TW'}, 'google_translate_element');
    DeleteGoogleIframe();
  }
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>


а запускаю скрипт на удаление этих элементов в футере.

Comment: @АлександрСалычев Попробуйте эти 2 скрипта переместить в конец `<body>`, перед скриптом с удалением элементов. По нынешним стандартам HTML 5.2 это будет вполне валидный код.

Comment: к сожалению, не работает

Comment: @АлександрСалычев Написанный Вами скрипт точно работает корректно и запускается? Сложно сказать в чем ошибка, когда не видишь общей картины. Попробуйте на [codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/) скинуть пример того, что Вы пытаетесь сделать.